# ImageMagick code in Python script

Tags: python, operating-system, imagemagick

I need to convert an image so as it only shows the color blue as a blob, is there any way I can run this code in a python script? Or how could I go about it?

The following code does the job but I don't know how to link it together, 
New to code, any advice, direction, links etc would be much appreciated.

## posterize

`sudo convert imgIn.jpg -posterize 2 imgOut.jpg`

## convert to blob

`sudo convert imgIn.jpg -matte \( +clone -fuzz 57% -opaque black -transparent blue \) -compose DstOut -composite imgOut.jpg`

Comment: There are actually several ImageMagick API bindings for Python, I would recommend using one of them. Here's Wand, for instance: http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.0/

Comment: Use one of the API's or simply use subprocess

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Padraic, could I ask you to show me some example code of how to implement this code using subprocess?

Comment: So you really need sudo?

Comment: I'm not sure, pretty new to code. This is one step of a program I hope to write, I have all the necessary code for every step I just don't know how to link it together. Hopefully if I can figure this out it will help me link the rest of the program.

Comment: @OwenLyons, I doubt you need sudo, I added working subprocess code, try removing the sudo and I am pretty sure it will be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call), passing the args as a list:

```
from subprocess import  check_call

check_call(["sudo","convert","imgIn.jpg", "-posterize","2","imgOut.jpg"])

check_call([ "sudo",'convert', 'imgIn.jpg', '-matte', '(', '+clone', '-fuzz', '57%', '-opaque', 'black', '-transparent', 'blue', ')', '-compose', 'DstOut', '-composite', 'imgOut.jpg'])
```

You will have to run the script with sudo, if you want to pass the password also you can use Popen writing the password to stdin:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p1 = Popen(["sudo", "-S", "convert", "imgIn.jpg", "-posterize", "2", "imgOut.jp"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

p1.stdin.write("password\n")
out, err = p1.communicate()
```